# how to plot the solution to this PDE?

Tags: maple

Maple generates a strange solution form for this PDE. I am having hard time plotting the solution.

The solution is in terms of infinite series. I set the number of terms to say 20, and then set the time to plot the solution at t=2 seconds. Then want to plot the solution now for `x=0..1`. But the plot comes out empty.

When I sample the solution, and use listplot, I get correct solution plot.

Here is MWE

```
restart;
pde:=diff(u(x,t),t)=diff(u(x,t),x$2)+x;
bc:=u(0,t)=0,u(1,t)=0;
ic:=u(x,0)=x*(1-x);
sol:=pdsolve({pde,ic,bc},u(x,t)):
sol:=value(sol);
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now set the number of terms to 20 and set `t=2`

```
sol2:=subs(t=2,sol):
sol2:=subs(infinity=20,sol2);
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The above is what I want to plot.

```
plot(rhs(sol2),x=0..1);
```

I get empty plot

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So had to manually sample it and use listplot

```
f:=x->rhs(sol2);
data:=[seq([x,f(x)],x=0..1,.01)]:
plots:-listplot(data);
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Solution looks correct, when I compare it to Mathematica's result. But Mathematica result is simpler as it does not have those integrals in the sum.

```
pde=D[u[x,t],t]==D[u[x,t],{x,2}]+x;
bc={u[0,t]==0,u[1,t]==0};
ic=u[x,0]==x(1-x);
DSolve[{pde,ic,bc},u[x,t],x,t];
%/.K[1]->n;
%/.Infinity->20;
%/.t->2;
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And the plot is

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Question is: How to plot Maple solution without manually sampling it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer seems to be that it is a regression in Maple 2017.3.

For me, your code works directly in Maple 2017.2 and Maple 2016.2 (without any unevaluated integrals). I will submit a bug report against the regression.

[edited] Let me know if any of these four ways work for your version (presumably Maple 2017.3).

```
restart;
pde:=diff(u(x,t),t)=diff(u(x,t),x$2)+x;
bc:=u(0,t)=0,u(1,t)=0;
ic:=u(x,0)=x*(1-x);
sol:=pdsolve({pde,ic,bc},u(x,t)):
sol:=value(sol);

sol5:=value(combine(subs([sum=Sum,t=2,infinity=20],sol))):
plot(rhs(sol5),x=0..1);

sol4:=combine(subs([sum=Sum,t=2,infinity=20],sol)):
(UseHardwareFloats,oldUHF):=false,UseHardwareFloats:
plot(rhs(sol4),x=0..1);
UseHardwareFloats:=oldUHF: # re-instate

sol2:=subs([sum=Sum,int=Int,t=2],sol):
# Switch integration and summation in second summand of rhs(sol).
sol3:=subsop(2=Sum(int(op([2,1,1],rhs(sol2)),op([2,2],rhs(sol2))),
                   op([2,1,2],rhs(sol2))),rhs(sol2)):
# Rename dummy index and combine summations.
sol3:=Sum(subs(n1=n,op([1,1],sol3))+op([2,1],sol3),
          subs(n1=n,op([1,2],sol3))):
# Curtail to first 20 terms.
sol3:=lhs(sol2)=subs(infinity=20,simplify(sol3));
plot(rhs(sol3),x=0..1);

F:=unapply(subs([Sum='add'],rhs(sol3)),x):
plot(F,0..1);
```

[edited] Here is yet another way, working for me in Maple 2017.3 on 64bit Linux.

It produces the plot quickly, and doesn't involve curtailing any sum at 20 terms. Note that it does not do your earlier step of `sol:=value(sol);` since it does active `int` rather than `Int` before hitting any `Sum` with `value`. It also uses an assumption on `x` corresponding to the plotting range.

```
restart;
pde:=diff(u(x,t),t)=diff(u(x,t),x$2)+x:
bc:=u(0,t)=0,u(1,t)=0:
ic:=u(x,0)=x*(1-x):
sol:=pdsolve({pde,ic,bc},u(x,t)):

solA:=subs(sum=Sum,value(eval(eval(sol,t=2),Int=int))) assuming x>0, x<1;

plot(rhs(solA),x=0..1) assuming x>0, x<1;
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. They all worked on 2017.3, Windows 7.  The plots shows up fine.

Comment: I added another way, which does not curtail the sum to 20 terms.